# java: Visual Studio Code doesn't read file

Tags: java

this program should print the contents of a text file called "a.txt" but with Visual Studio Code it doesn't work, reporting the error below.
I compiled with Jcreator and Geany and compile. Could anyone tell me why it doesn't work on Visual Studio Code?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        //String pathFileName = "inputFile.txt"; 

        //File inputFile = new File(pathFileName);
        File inputFile = new File("a.txt");
        Scanner scannerDaFile = null;
        try {
         scannerDaFile = new Scanner (inputFile);
         System.out.println("---------------- OUTPUT TEXT: "+inputFile.getName()+" --------------------");
         while(scannerDaFile.hasNextLine()) {
           System.out.println(scannerDaFile.nextLine());
         }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
        finally {
          if(scannerDaFile!=null) {
          scannerDaFile.close();
          }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Well it doesnt find the file. Are you sure your program can find it, maybe you could add the whole path to the file...

Comment: See above. Your current code is only going to check the directory where your executable is generated.

Comment: @JakobFyes, i'm sure that this program can find the file because its work on Geany and JCreator, but not in Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently and turns out when you run your java from vs code your build is stored somewhere else.
In order to place the txt files where my program can find it I followed the following steps:

1. Print the execution dir somewhere in your code

   System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
2. Open add the txt files or folders into that directory.

A better way to prevent this problem to happen is to use the full path of the files.